# jQuery blur function not working first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur

I am currently having a problem on blur() function because it needs the user first to click outside the frame or in page body before it works.

Here is the link for the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( window ).blur(function(){
      alert("you click the IFRAME!");
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gaoj6fzs/15/

What I want is that, the alert will prompt when I click the IFRAME without needing to click first any part outside the frame.

Comment: can you explain why would you need blur? why not to go with click or smth like that

Comment: .click() function will not work on IFRAME.

Comment: I think op wants to notify user when refocusing from parent window into iframe. Click would fire every time you click on something in the iframe. My best guess would be to set $(iframe).on('focus',function(){});

Comment: $("iframe").on('focus',function(){}); but still did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the click/focus event.

```
// click
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( window ).click(function(){
      alert("you click the IFRAME!");
  });
});

// focus
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( window ).focus(function(){
      alert("you click the IFRAME!");
  });
});
```

Comment: .click() in this case will not work. I only want to alert the user once he / she click the IFRAME but not when he / she click outside the IFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is find the contents of the iframe and if the contents match what you wanted then the user clicked on the iframe else did not

Now check it

```
  $('iframe').load(function(){

  $(this).contents().find("body").on('click', function(event) {     alert('test'); });
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but event.target did not work if I click the IFRAME.

Comment: There is no error in the console. It works in the other element except for IFRAME maybe because IFRAME did not support onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript :**

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find("body").on('click', function(event) { alert('test'); });
});
$('iframe').attr("src","JavaScript:'iframe content'");
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/km6sz3y8/)

> **Note 1:** Both pages are in the same domain.
>
> **Note 2:**  If you have two or more iframes, you must give separate id's for them

Comment: yes, thank you! But the content of my iframe is in different domain.